# Getting multiple values in dictionary

Tags: python

I want to get the values of a key in a dictionary. After working with googlemaps and I got my result, I want to just get the values I need and move on. But it seems not to be working for me.

The result:

```
>>>the_distance= gmaps.distance_matrix(origins, destinations)
>>> print the_distance
{u'status': u'OK', u'rows': [{u'elements': [{u'duration': {u'text': u'27 mins', u'value': 1599}, u'distance': {u'text': u'11.9 km', u'value': 11874},  u'status': u'OK'}]}], u'origin_addresses': [u'Lamu, Kayyy'], u'destination_addresses': [u'20 Dave Ave, Mars, Amsterdam']}
```

Looking at the result, the key 'rows' has different values. I only need the duration: `27 mins` and distance: `11.9km`.

I tried

```
>>>the_distance.values()[1:3]
```

I got the same result as above.

I also tried

```
>>the_distance['rows'][:2]
```

I got

```
{u'status': u'OK', u'rows': [{u'elements': [{u'duration': {u'text': u'27 mins', u'value': 1599}, u'distance': {u'text': u'11.9 km', u'value': 11874}, u'status': u'OK'}]}]
```

what do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

access to the dictionary could be done as follows.

```
cool_variable = the_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]
cool_variable['duration']['text']
cool_variable['distance']['text']
```

Comment: Damn!! how did I missed this! I suck mehn!! It worked! Thanks!

Comment: You don't suck!  We all need some help from time to time.  Glad i could assist.

Comment: Thanks Kosch! Will accept the answer in 6 mins time (SO won't let me do that now.)